# Disable vibrate for push notification using PARSE iOS

Tags: parse-platform

Is there a way to disable the vibrate and sound when receiving a push using Parse for iOS?

I'd like the push to make no sound or vibrate and simply show up on the receiving device.

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

please remove sound paramter from the code on server where you sending push notification

e.g.

```
{
    "aps": {
        "badge": 15,
        "alert": "Hello World",
        **"sound": "push.caf" // Remove this sound paramter**
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Objective C, you need to remove it from the AppDelegate.m where it registers for notifications. You code should read something like

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge) categories:nil]];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
```

You could remove the Sound from here to read

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge) categories:nil]];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
```

Hope this helps